# удаление записи из БД sqlite3 по нажатию кнопки в telegram bot на python

Tags: sqlite3, telebot

библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI и sqlite3.
Хендлер по команде выводит все записи из базы для текущего пользователя и под каждой записью добавляет инлайн кнопку, нажатие на которую должно удалить соответствующую запись из базы. С выведением проблем нет, не могу сообразить как корректно организовать обработку нажатия на инлайн кнопку под конкретным сообщением. В моем текущем коде получается так, что DELETE FROM обращается к последнему значению цикла for и то, по какой-то причине, удаление не работает и ошибок не выдает тоже. Подскажите, плиз, в какую сторону думать.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['get'])
def get_from_my_list(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Удалить", callback_data='del')
    keyboard.add(button)

    with sqlite3.connect('users_data.db',check_same_thread=False) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        query = """SELECT wish FROM wishes WHERE user_id = {}""".format(user_id)
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        for i in data:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, i,reply_markup=keyboard)

            @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
            def answer(call):
                message = call.message
                if call.data == 'del':
                    query = """DELETE FROM wishes WHERE wish = ?"""
                    cursor.execute(query,(i[0],))
                    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Удалено')
```

Answer (score 1):

допустим у нас есть таблица в бд с полями:

- chat_id
- username

Функция создания клавиатуры:

```
def kb(chat_id):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Удалить", callback_data="['del', '" + str(chat_id) + "']")
    keyboard.add(button)
    return keyboard
```

здесь мы добавляем в `callback_data` дополнительный параметр - аргумент `chat_id`.

функция `start`:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    with sqlite3.connect('test.db', check_same_thread=False) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in data:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, i[0], reply_markup=kb(i[0]))
```

и хэндлер обработки `callback`:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data.startswith("['del'"):
        print(ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1])
        with sqlite3.connect('test.db', check_same_thread=False) as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = ?", (ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1],))
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Удалено')
```

к `call.data` добавился `startswith` - Строка-префикс (либо кортеж строк), в наличии которой требуется удостовериться.

Таким образом, если `call.data` начинается с `del` условие будет выполнено.

используя `ast.literal_eval` мы можем получить дополнительные параметры переданные в `call.data`:

`['del', '12**11']` - это обычный список, второй элемент это `chat_id` переданный в `callback_data` функции `kb()`.

теперь мы можем передать в запрос к БД необходимое условие для удаления.